# Electron opening link inside the same window

Tags: javascript, html, electron

I am new with eletron framework and i am using below code to open a new window from my electron app, but how can i open a link inside the same/parent window?

My parent window is a HTML file.

```
 <a href="#" onclick="myFunction()">google</a> 

                   <script>
                        function myFunction() {
                        const remote = require('electron').remote;
                        const BrowserWindow = remote.BrowserWindow;

                        var win = new BrowserWindow({ width: 800, height: 600 });
                        win.loadURL('http://www.google.com');
                        }
                        </script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<a href="http://www.google.com" >google</a>` and if it doesn't open on the same window try adding the attribute target="_self"

`<a href="http://www.google.com" target="_self">google</a>`

hope it helps !

Comment: Thanks for the response, it worked without the target self.